# How to connect PostgreSQL installed on ubuntu using R

Tags: r, postgresql

I have installed the Ubuntu postgreSQL very quickly, using the following command,

```
$sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

And I login into the database using he following command,

```
$sudo -i -u postgres

$psql
```

Then I create the table and index of my database in it. I can see that the database is correctly imported, and have index created, and the database is ready to go.

But the problem is in the R program, I use the library(RPostgreSQL) to connect to the database, I have filled the connection details as follows,

```
connection <- dbConnect(driver, dbname='testchr22', host='localhost', port=5432, user= 'postgres', password='')
```

But all the connection failed.

But my problem is the database connection always have problems,  I didn’t set up the password, I don’t know what password should include.

I have always encounter the following errors, forever, and don't know where I got it wrong.

Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : RS-DBI driver: ()
Calls: batchAnnotate -> dbConnect -> dbConnect -> postgresqlNewConnection
Execution halted

Comment: You need to search for "Posgresql on Ubuntu". There are many tutorials that show you how to set this up. You've done the first step. There are many more, and you can learn about them in the tutorials.

Comment: thanks very much. I will read those tutorials first.